# Return result from inner stream listen DART

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to return result from function if stream returns no connection value.

So i have outer function and inner function. How can i return result from outer inside inner?

```dart
Future<bool> send() async {

        var subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {

            if(result == ConnectivityResult.none)
                throw("No connectivity");
// Need to stop `send` function here and return some result
        });

        await doSomeWork();

        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Future` returned by `send` can only be completed once, while the `Stream` may have multiple events emitted - you can't complete it with `true` and then later complete again with `false` because some new event came through the stream.

You could decide that the return value from `send` depends on the *first* event in the stream:

```
Future<bool> send() async {
  var result = await Connectivity().onConnectivityChange.first;
  if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
    // handle no connection
    return false;
  }
  await doSomeWork(); // only happens if the first result was not `none`
  return true;
}
```

Or you'll need to make a decision on what it means for a `none` connectivity result to come through *after* `doSomeWork()` was already called and the `Future` returned from `send` already completed.